# What's wrong with this pair of simple Bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script

This pair of very simple Bash scripts does not work the way I intend them to on AlmaLinux 8.6.

The first script acts as a simple gateway that performs pre/post-processing in front of a Unix socket. It also calls the second script for logging purposes. Failure of the logging command should not prevent fulfillment of the gateway function. (Note that the scripts shown below are contrived versions meant to highlight the problems; the actual scripts are more complex.)

<del>The problem with this first script is that errors from the logging command are NOT ignored and make the whole script fail, despite the use of the `... || true` construct. Why so?</del>

**The consumer of this gateway service is expecting its response through *stdout*, and some error messages from *cat* seem to somehow end up on that channel. It appears that it not the below script that fails upon logging failure, but the consumer of the gateway. I am currently doing more testing to try and find where the issue lies. I will update this question with additional details.**

Edit Oct 22: The problem was in the interface with the consumer of the pipeline. See comments below.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

sock_file="/path/to/my.sock"
in_cmd="/path/to/my_in.sh"
out_cmd="/path/to/my_out.sh"
log_cmd="/path/to/my_log.sh"  # See second script below

exec 3<&0
$log_cmd <&3 >/dev/null || true
exec 3<&-

exec $in_cmd | nc -U -N "$sock_file" | $out_cmd
```

The problem with this second script is that it simply does not log anything. I would have thought it would get its *stdin* set to the FD 3 in the parent script above?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

log_file="/tmp/in.log"

stdbuf -iL cat >>"$log_file"
```

Also, — and this is more a question to try and explain a warning message that seems to contradict actual experience — when I call *cat* through *stdbuf* as above, I get on *stderr* "*stdbuf: line buffering stdin is meaningless*". However, if I make input to *cat* unbuffered, either by using `stdbuf -i0 ...` or by not using *stdbuf* at all, the script fails with "*cat: -: Resource temporarily unavailable*". So I guess line-buffering *stdin* isn't so meaningless after all, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce that issue with the first script. Are you sure it's about `errexit`, does it work if you disable that? What does it show if you run the whole thing under `set -x`?

Comment: These seem like three separate and mostly unrelated questions. Please post each as its own post: each Question here should be asking _one_ question so we can provide _one_ answer. Or does one script call the other? If so, please clarify that and tell us which script is which.

Comment: I made some further tests following @ilkkachu's suggestion. You are right, the culprit is not that part of the script. The failure happens when the logging script fails with the "*cat: -: Resource temporarily unavailable*" message. I guess that somehow this message makes it's way to the parent script's output. In my (more complete) version of the script, I have a ```>/dev/null``` that should capture and nullify such output so it doesn't interfere with the gateway function (I have updated the listing above with it), but that does not seem to work as intended.

Comment: `>` only redirects the standard output (stdout, file descriptor 1) stream, not standard error (stderr, fd 2) which is commonly used for error messages (like the name says). You'd need `> /dev/null 2>&1` to redirect stderr also to `/dev/null` (`2>&1` says to make fd 2 point to where ever fd 1 now points)

Comment: @terdon, we can forget the third question, I can live with it and I wouldn't bother posting a question just for that. The first two questions, it turns out following ilkkachu's comment, might be related to one another and I'm not convinced that they should be addressed separately.

Comment: hmm, actually, what system are you on? On my Debian, `stdbuf -iL cat` gives an error from _stdbuf_: "stdbuf: line buffering stdin is meaningless".  Not that I can think why that would give the "Resource temporarily unavailable" error. That's the error you'd get if some system call (like a read) would block, but you've asked for non-blocking mode. But it could be something else. If you're on Linux, see what `strace stdbuf -iL cat` shows as the last system calls, especially one that returns with EAGAIN (or EWOULDBLOCK)

Comment: @ilkkachu, thanks for the suggestion ```...2>&1```, but I don't think it applies here. I updated the question with more details. I am on AlmaLinux 8.6 (question updated with it too). I understand why the ```stdbuf...``` part works the way it does, but not why I get a warning that states it's meaningless to do so when it so obviously isn't. As terdon pointed out though, maybe we can leave this part out for now. I will need a bit more time for additional digging into the main problem.

Comment: @mesr, ...right, you had mentioned that "is meaningless" error there already. Sorry. Anyway, it's not meaningless here in that having `stdbuf` face that error stops it from running `cat` to begin with, while with the other choices, `cat` runs and gets the error it gets, for whatever reason. I'm not exactly sure what the point of `exec 3<&0` + `<&3` is, it looks like it'd just let the program read from stdin like it would by default. I wonder if you could get that if the fd that eventually goes to `cat` would be set nonblocking somewhere else already...

Comment: ... yes, that would do, I tried: `perl -MFcntl -e 'sysopen(STDIN, "/dev/stdin", O_NONBLOCK | O_RDONLY); exec("cat")'` Is there some reason whatever runs that script would pass it a non-blocking fd? Is that why the stdbuf is there...? I'm not sure it helps, though, AFAIU `stdbuf` hacks the buffering settings in the C library, while `O_NONBLOCK` affects system call behaviour when waiting for data.

Comment: @ilkkachu, that's interesting. So the "*...is meaningless*" message might be meaningful after all. I thought it was just a warning and not an error, but it looks like you are right, it does prevent *cat* from running. The purpose of ```exec 3>&0``` is to avoid having the logging part of the script consume *stdin* before the gateway part gets to read it. By duplicating the FD in this way, the logging and the gateway parts of the script each get independent pointers, or am I wrong? I don't have a lot of experience with shell scripting so it's quite possible that my understanding is flawed.

Comment: @mesr, no, sorry, you don't get independent pointers. You'd need to actually open the file separately to get that. And if it's a (named) pipe or a terminal, that doesn't help either, e.g. pipes only have a single buffer of unread data, not a buffer for each individual reader. You could use `tee` and a process substitution here: `tee >(my_log.sh) | nc ...` or something like that. Though it does come to mind that this might be a case where some other programming language than then shell would be better...

Comment: @Ilkkachu, it turns out the consumer of the script (socat) was in non-blocking mode, which *cat* and *tee* don't play nice with. Switching the socat connection back to blocking mode made things even worse since apparently in that context that means page — not line — caching. The only way we managed to make it work was by keeping the pipeline in non-blocking mode and hooking somewhere else for logging. Good enough for now. Thank you for your help which was instrumental in understanding what was going on. If you care to write an answer, even short, I'll accept it, so you get the points.